# Compile module with Gradle using Makefile

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, makefile, or-tools

I have a Java/Gradle project with 3 different modules. One of these modules (let's call it *orModule*) has a dependency on [or-tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools), which unfortunately is not yet available through some public repository (like Maven) and therefore it has to be built from the source.

The team that's developing or-tools provides a Makefile for compiling/building the project and this is what I've been using so far. To be more specific I compile my orModule using the Makefile and then I run my main Java class, which belongs in the main module. Below are two screenshots of the Run Configurations I use for the two modules.

My goal is to move these configurations in the Gradle build system because I need the project to eventually be built with Gradle.

[image: MainClass Run Configuration]
[image: OrModule Run Configuration]

For the MainClass, I've added the following configuration in the root `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.some.package.MainClass'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Djava.library.path=/orModule/lib']
```

And I think this is correct. However, I'm not sure how to "move" the Makefile configuration inside Gradle. The following is one of the alternatives that I've tried in the `orModule/build.gradle` but it fails.

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'make', ['EX=src/main/java/com/some/path/OrClass.java','PKG=com/some/package'], 'cjava', file('Makefile')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

Any help on how to correctly write this configuration with Gradle, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for info, i'm working on:
1) OR-Tools CMake based build (Currently C++ and Python BUT not Java yet...).
2) Hope to provide soon a Maven Package also if you want a prebuilt package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by getting rid of the Makefile altogether. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52790798/1680301) the original answer.

This was solved quite some time ago so if anyone has a simpler solution by now, please post it and I'll change the accepted answer.