# Installing Google or-tools with gradle project on Windows 10 (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: java, visual-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, or-tools

Is it possible to install the library on IntelliJ Idea?

or do I have to use Visual Studio 2017?

If so, how do I install it? I find the google documentation confusing.

Comment: Hi Mattia! I see you accepted an answer so I assume you solved your issue. Could you please post your relevant gradle configuration so that we have a more concrete answer? I'm struggling a bit with the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case anyone else comes here, this is my configuration for building and running OR-tools with Gradle.

First of all, I have a top-level project where I have application-related code, called `suite`, and a module where I have separated all the OR-Tools related code, called `optimization`. In the `optimization` module, I have a folder `lib` which contains the following files (not sure if you need all of them):

```
com.google.ortools.jar
libcvrptw_lib.so
libdimacs.so
libjniortools.so
libortools.so
```

As you can see, there's no `protobuf.jar` here -this comes later. Then I added the following to my existing top-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.6'
    }
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'application'

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Djava.library.path=optimization/lib"]

mainClassName = 'com.package.name.MainClass'
```

Note that for `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` you have to change the path to your `lib` folder. And of course, update `mainClassName` to your main class.

And finally, in the `build.gradle` of my `optimization` module I added the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('lib/com.google.ortools.jar')
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0'
    ...
}
```

The above compiles `ortools.jar` from the `lib` folder and downloads the `protobuf-java` library from `mavenCentral`.

PS. Don't forget to load the `jniortools` library in your Java class that accesses OR-tools:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("jniortools");
}
```

Obviously, you don't need sub-modules to make this work - this is just my implementation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that there is also a Maven artifact [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:io.github.oliviercailloux%20a:google-or-tools). (See also the [project](https://github.com/oliviercailloux/google-or-tools-java) and the [issue](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/202).)

Answer (score 2):

We provide prebuilt binaries archives
cf https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/java/windows#installing-or-tools so you don't need visual studio to only consume it...

Then to use it in Gradle you'll need to extract the `lib/com.google.ortools.jar`, `lib/protobuf.jar`, the JNI file `jniortools.dll` which may also depends on the `ortools.lib`.

Take a look at the Makefile rule `rjava` to know the parameters to set and try to add it to your gradle project...

Something like this:

```
javac -d output_dir -cp lib/com.google.ortools.jar;lib/protobuf.jar YourFile.java
java -Djava.library.path=lib -cp output_dir;lib/com.google.ortools.jar;lib/protobuf.jar YourFile
```

So you must know how class path and java library path are managed in Gradle....